# in tomcat's threadpool,When a thread return to pool ,does the threadlocal values reset or remove?

Tags: java, thread-local

in tomcat's thread-pool,When a thread is used to store some values and finally 
 the request is end and the thread return to thread-pool,does the thread-local values reset or remove?

Comment: What's the difference between resetting and removing? Why would it do either? And why are you asking?

Comment: emmm，i mean remove.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328437/will-the-threadlocal-object-be-cleared-after-thread-returned-to-thread-pool

Answer (score 1):

No, the values are not removed because you might want to use the same threadLocal value next time when your request get that thread from the pool.

If you are concerned about memory leaks then this might help you: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection