# Where to inject custom audit service in a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, audit

I have a multi-module spring boot app, and every module has a dependency on an audit service (which is defined in a 'helper' module, only has a method called audit() and all it actually does is calling another application with WebClient, sending some data about the current user).

Currently, it is being injected into each module's service class and it just sends some hardcoded data (because the authentication wasn't ready yet), but now I need to extract the user info (from the OAuth JWT claims) and actually pass that along with the token to make an authenticated request to the audit application.

*pseudocode of one of the modules' main service*

```
class ActualService {
    
   AuditService auditSvc
   ActualRepository actualRepo

   public void updateSomething(RequestDTO request, JWT authenticatedUser) {
       ....doSomething()
       auditSvc.audit(someHardcodedValues)
   }

}
```

What would be a proper way of accomplishing this? I'm thinking about injecting the audit service into each module's controller and call the audit method  (and passing it the entire JWT) after calling the actual main service method and before returning the response to the client.

*like this*

```
class ActualController {

    AuditService auditSvc
    ActualService actualService

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> updateSomething(RequestDTO request, JWT authenticatedUser) {
       actualService.updateSomething(request, authenticatedUser)
       auditSvc.audit(authenticatedUser)
       return ResponseEntity.OK
    } 

}
```

But I don't know if it's a good approach. Any sensible ideas welcome, thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use a ThreadLocal to keep the JWT token. The ThreadLocal variable can be created inside a filter and then store the token inside the variable.

This link has a similar answer but for RestTemplate,
[Propagate HTTP header (JWT Token) over services using spring rest template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46729203/propagate-http-header-jwt-token-over-services-using-spring-rest-template)